# How to inherit methods from a parent class in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

When inheriting classes in C++ I understand members are inherited. But how does one inherit the methods as well?

For example, in the below code, I'd like the method "getValues" to be accessible not through just CPoly, but also by any class that inherits it. So one can call "getValues" on CRect directly.

```
class CPoly {
  private:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void getValues (int* a, int* b)
      { *a=width; *b=height;}
  };

class CRect: public CPoly {
  public:
    int area ()
      { return (width * height); }
  };
```

In other words, is there any way to inherit methods for simple generic methods like getters and setters?

Comment: Make the `width` and `height` variables `protected` (instead of `private`) members of `CPoly` in order to access them within `CRect`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* call `getValues` by using `CRect`, because `getValues` is inherited. The term "methods" is not defined by C++. If you refer to non-static member functions - they are members and are inherited to derived classes.

Your error is not that `getValues` isn't inherited, but that you try to access the inaccessible members `width` and `height`.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response! Changing from private to protected allowed the CRect to work as expected:

Answer (score 0):

Everything is inherited, there is no distinction between member variables and member functions in this respect.

In `CPoly` if you want people who use your class to see the members (whether functions or variables) you use `public`.  For the classes that derive from `CPoly` if you want them to be able to use the members (whether functions or variables), then you must make them either `public` or `protected`.

In the derived type `CRect`, when you specify the base class, you also must specify a default access member for all of the inherited members (whether functions or variables).  if you specify `public`, all of the members inherited that are `public` will remain `public`.  If you specify `protected`, all of the members inherited that are `public` or `protected` will be `protected`.  If you specify `private`, all of the members inherited will become `private`.